# Awk: filter string + count number of lines?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, ubuntu, awk

I have some JSON data:

```
    "Item1": {
      "foo": null,
      "version": "bar",
      "result": null,
    },
    "Item2": {
      "foo": null,
      "version": "bar",
      "result": null,
    },
    "Item3": {
      "foo": null,
      "version": "bar",
      "result": null,
    },
```

With `awk` I'm able to filter strings:

```
$ awk '/version/' /tmp/json
      "version": "bar",
      "version": "bar",
      "version": "bar",
```

I'm trying to count the number of lines and get the following result without piping, pure awk.

```
$ awk '/version/' /tmp/json | wc -l
3
```

Examples online show how to use `END` and `NR` but this doesn't produce the results I'm looking for:

```
$ awk '/version/{print NR}' /tmp/json
3
8
13
```

or

```
$ awk 'END/version/{print NR}' /tmp/json
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near /version/
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a JSON parser like `jq` for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really insist on doing this in `awk`, all you need to do is increment a variable for each matching line and then, once all lines have been processed, print that variable:

```
$ awk '/version/{c++}END{print c}' file
3
```

Or, if you want to get a `0` printed when there are no matches (the above will just print an empty line), use:

```
awk '/version/{c++}END{print c+0}' file
```

Finally to print *only* if there is at least one match (so no output, instead of an empty line, when there are no matches), use:

```
awk '/version/{c++}END{ if(c) print c}'
```

Comment: @edmorton I saw you used the `+0` in a comment as well, but what's the point of it here? The variable is only ever going to have numerical values, it is _exclusively_ used in `c++` and then in `print c` so this can't be as a safety net to make sure it's a number. As it stands, this just causes it to print a useless `0` when there are no matches. I find it much more practical to have no output when there are no matches.

Comment: The original script will output a blank line, not no output, when there are no matches. If `version` never appears in the input then in the END section `c` will never have been incremented or even set and so it'll still have the value zero-or-null and be printed as null unless you force it to be a number by adding 0. If you like having no output in that scenario (which I can definitely understand) then make it `if (c) print c` instead but `grep -c 'version'` would output `0` in that case and IMHO that makes sense and it's worth replicating the behavior here.

Comment: @EdMorton I see, yes. Fair enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } /version/ { count++ } END { printf( "%d\n", count ) }' datafile.json
```

But, more simply:

```
grep -c 'version' datafile.json
```

Comment: The awk code doesn't need to be that lengthy: `awk '/version/{c++} END{print c+0}'`

Comment: @EdMorton: why the `+0` ¿? Is this to enforce numeric type ?

Comment: @Cbhihe it ensures you get a number `0` output instead of a null string when there are no `version`s in the input.

Comment: It does not _need_ to be that lengthy, but I generally write more bellicose code on venues such as this in the interest of making the intent and logic _clear_ rather than _short_. (Also, `+0` is no longer necessary when the value is initialized as in the code presented in my answer)